# Semantic UI table data filling from JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

How can I fill my table data using a JSON file? I want to change the styles using CSS classes in Semantic UI when I load the data using a JSON file. I have hard-coded data in the table (which I want to change with the data from JSON)

Below is the hard coded table structure:

```
<table class="ui black table" id="tableCustomerDetails">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Custome Name</th>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Special Approval Pending</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>
                    <img src="<c:url value='/resources/img/deadpool.jpeg'/>" class="ui left floated mini rounded image">
                    <span class="content">
                        Matthew
                        <div class="sub header">Fabric Design
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui blue label">
                    Pending
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui left labeled icon buttons">
                    <div class="ui mini blue button" id="buttonPendingSpecialApproval">
                        <i class="chevron circle right icon"></i>
                        Yes
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>
                    <img src="<c:url value='/resources/img/avatar/people/Rick.png'/>"
                        class="ui left floated mini rounded image">
                    <span class="content">
                        Matthew
                        <span class="sub header">Fabric Design
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </h4>
            </td>
            <td>310</td>
            <td>
                <div class="ui green label">
                    Submitted
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery, react or any tools?

Comment: Yes. I'm using jquery. I 'm using jsp for front end to write the code.and java to back end and spring architecture

Comment: I added the jquery tag for you

Answer (score 0):

Use basic JavaScript:

```
const data = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById("class1").className = data.A.class;
document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML = data.A.content;
document.getElementById("img1").src = data.A.img;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "A"?

Comment: It's just an example of parsed data from `JSON`.